# How to Delete one object in an array of objects in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

# Not sure if I need to load all these assemblies
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll';
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll';
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll';
 # Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll';

$App = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application; 

$PackageFullPath = 'C:\SSISPackage.dtsx'; # This is the SSIS package and has some connection managers. 

$Package = $App.LoadPackage($PackageFullPath, $null, 0);

$Package.Connections # this gives an array of objects with connection managers and I would like to remove one of them. 

$Package.Connections | Get-member # Object: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager

$App.SaveToXml($PackageFullPath, $Package, $null) # Here I would like to save the package again and when I open the solution i Visual Studio I would like it to be gone.
```

Comment: I don't understand how both code samples relate to each other. Can you clarify? Also, a short example output of the pipeline that you want to filter, would be helpful.

Comment: As for the PowerShell command: If you capture its output in a variable, you'll get an _array_ of _objects_ (the `Select-Object -Property *` seems redundant). You're already filtering the list of services with `Where-Object`, so you can add another filter criterion to exclude the service you want to delete - rather than trying to delete it from the array after the fact (arrays don't support deletion).

Comment: @zett42: The code sample that can run is just an example of the shape of the result when I have `$p.property`.

Comment: @mklement0: The code with `Get-Service` is only an example of how the output looks when I have `$P.property` loaded from a file.

Comment: @mklement0: I do need to delete one element of the array, because my plan to save the object to disk. Thanks for the terminology help with _array of objects_.

Comment: Understood, @xhr489, but my point was that you technically cannot delete an element from an array, because it is a fixed-size data structure. Your only option is to create a _new_ array with the element of interest omitted. If `$P.property` already is an array, apply a `Where-Object` filter to _it_ and capture the result in a(n invariably new) array.

Comment: @mklement0: I have excluded the element from the array and assigned it to a variable `$x`. Then I try to overwrite the original property with `$P.property = $x` but this gives an error that the property is ReadOnly. I do not understand what I should do then. I need to end with `$App.SaveToXml($FullPath, $P, $null)` where the element from the array is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Package.Connections` contains a [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.connections) instance, which has a [`.Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.connections.remove#microsoft-sqlserver-dts-runtime-connections-remove(system-object)) method.

Therefore - assuming you know the index, name, or ID of the connection to remove - do the following:

```
# Determine the the connection to remove, which can be specified
# as:
# "name, index, ID, or identity of the ConnectionManager object to remove."
$toRemove = 42 # sample index

$Package.Connections.Remove($toRemove)
```

Comment: You use the word "instance" above. Can you please explain when something is an instance?

Comment: @xhr489, thanks for pointing out the typo - fixed now. _Instance_ is another way of saying _object_, and is typically used to refer to an object as a concrete embodiment of its _type_ (class).